# Qt cannot find opencv4android libraries

Tags: android, c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator

I want to use the opencv4android libraries, but Qt doesn't find the libraries. Here's my code:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/

LIBS += -LC:\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs\armeabi-v7a\
-libopencv_androidcamera.a \
-libopencv_flann\
-libopencv_imgproc\
-libopencv_highgui\
-libopencv_features2d\
-libopencv_calib3d\
-libopencv_ml\
-libopencv_objdetect\
-libopencv_photo\
-libopencv_stitching\
-libopencv_superres\
-libopencv_ts\
-libopencv_video\
-libopencv_videostab\
-libopencv_java.so\
-libopencv_info.so
```

And it gives me the following error for each library:

> error: cannot find -lopencv_androidcamera.a
>
> error: cannot find -library name-

Any idea of how can I solve this?

Comment: change `-libopencv_androidcamera.a` to `-lopencv_androidcamera`

Comment: now it doesn't give me errors on mingw,but it gives me erros on android